How to implement server-side pagination with TanStack Table and trigger data fetch on page change?
I am trying to implement server-side pagination using TanStack Table in my Next.js project. I have followed the instructions provided in the TanStack Table documentation. The table is displaying correctly, but I am having trouble figuring out how to trigger the data fetch when the "Next" or "Previous" button is pressed.

See https://github.com/sadmann7/shadcn-table

I would recommend you take a look at this project that uses Shadcn Data Table component: https://github.com/sadmann7/shadcn-table
The pros of using this table is that it has server side pagination enabled, has advanced filters, and can be customized according to your needs.
